# How to rectify this program using phonegap with json

Tags: ajax, cordova

I am using phonegap with json .here i got a error
    index/html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />

    <script src="phonegap-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/load-json.js"></script>

    <script>
        function onBodyLoad() {     
            document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
        }


    </script>

</head>
<body onload="onBodyLoad()">
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>

Json.js



$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).bind('deviceready', function(){
        var output = $('#output');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http:192.168.1.3:8000/index',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
            timeout: 5000,
            success: function(data, status){
                $.each(data, function(i,item){ 
                    var landmark = '<h1>'+item.name+'</h1>'
                    + '<p>'+item.latitude+'<br>'
                    + item.longitude+'</p>';

                    output.append(landmark);
                });
            },
            error: function(){
               output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
            }
        });
    });
});



 01-12 15:08:52.050: I/System.out(338): loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
    01-12 15:08:52.050: I/System.out(338): url=file:///android_asset/www/index.html baseUrl=file:///android_asset/www
    01-12 15:08:52.230: W/System.err(338): java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
    01-12 15:08:52.230: W/System.err(338):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.socket(Native Method)
    01-12 15:08:52.230: W/System.err(338):  at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.socket(BlockGuard.java:335)
    01-12 15:08:52.230: W/System.err(338):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:216)
    01-12 15:08:52.230: W/System.err(338):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainServerSocketImpl.create(PlainServerSocketImpl.java:40)
    01-12 15:08:52.240: W/System.err(338):  at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:120)
    01-12 15:08:52.240: W/System.err(338):  at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:74)
    01-12 15:08:52.240: W/System.err(338):  at com.phonegap.CallbackServer.run(CallbackServer.java:177)
    01-12 15:08:52.240: W/System.err(338):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
    01-12 15:08:53.299: D/szipinf(338): Initializing inflate state
    01-12 15:08:53.299: D/szipinf(338): Initializing zlib to inflate
    01-12 15:08:53.349: D/szipinf(338): Initializing inflate state
    01-12 15:08:53.349: D/szipinf(338): Initializing zlib to inflate
    01-12 15:08:54.819: D/PhoneGapLog(338): file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 13 : ReferenceError: Can't find variable: onDeviceReady
    01-12 15:08:54.819: E/Web Console(338): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: onDeviceReady at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:13
    01-12 15:09:15.029: D/dalvikvm(338): GC_CONCURRENT freed 361K, 52% free 2806K/5767K, external 884K/1038K, paused 6ms+4ms
    01-12 15:09:45.860: I/System.out(377): loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
    01-12 15:09:45.909: I/System.out(377): url=file:///android_asset/www/index.html baseUrl=file:///android_asset/www
    01-12 15:09:46.299: W/System.err(377): java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
    01-12 15:09:46.299: W/System.err(377):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.socket(Native Method)
    01-12 15:09:46.299: W/System.err(377):  at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.socket(BlockGuard.java:335)
    01-12 15:09:46.299: W/System.err(377):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:216)
    01-12 15:09:46.299: W/System.err(377):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainServerSocketImpl.create(PlainServerSocketImpl.java:40)
    01-12 15:09:46.299: W/System.err(377):  at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:120)
    01-12 15:09:46.299: W/System.err(377):  at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:74)
    01-12 15:09:46.299: W/System.err(377):  at com.phonegap.CallbackServer.run(CallbackServer.java:177)
    01-12 15:09:46.299: W/System.err(377):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
    01-12 15:09:46.849: D/szipinf(377): Initializing inflate state
    01-12 15:09:46.849: D/szipinf(377): Initializing zlib to inflate
    01-12 15:09:46.869: D/szipinf(377): Initializing inflate state
    01-12 15:09:46.869: D/szipinf(377): Initializing zlib to inflate
    01-12 15:09:48.100: D/PhoneGapLog(377): file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 13 : ReferenceError: Can't find variable: onDeviceReady
    01-12 15:09:48.100: E/Web Console(377): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: onDeviceReady at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:13
    01-12 15:10:10.170: I/System.out(416): loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
    01-12 15:10:10.249: I/System.out(416): url=file:///android_asset/www/index.html baseUrl=file:///android_asset/www
    01-12 15:10:10.559: W/System.err(416): java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
    01-12 15:10:10.559: W/System.err(416):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.socket(Native Method)
    01-12 15:10:10.559: W/System.err(416):  at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.socket(BlockGuard.java:335)
    01-12 15:10:10.569: W/System.err(416):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:216)
    01-12 15:10:10.569: W/System.err(416):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainServerSocketImpl.create(PlainServerSocketImpl.java:40)
    01-12 15:10:10.569: W/System.err(416):  at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:120)
    01-12 15:10:10.569: W/System.err(416):  at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:74)
    01-12 15:10:10.569: W/System.err(416):  at com.phonegap.CallbackServer.run(CallbackServer.java:177)
    01-12 15:10:10.569: W/System.err(416):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
    01-12 15:10:11.080: D/szipinf(416): Initializing inflate state
    01-12 15:10:11.080: D/szipinf(416): Initializing zlib to inflate
    01-12 15:10:11.100: D/szipinf(416): Initializing inflate state
    01-12 15:10:11.100: D/szipinf(416): Initializing zlib to inflate
    01-12 15:10:12.359: D/PhoneGapLog(416): file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 13 : ReferenceError: Can't find variable: onDeviceReady
    01-12 15:10:12.359: E/Web Console(416): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: onDeviceReady at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:13
    01-12 15:10:32.759: D/dalvikvm(416): GC_CONCURRENT freed 362K, 52% free 2806K/5767K, external 884K/1038K, paused 6ms+4ms
    01-12 15:11:42.329: D/dalvikvm(416): GC_CONCURRENT freed 489K, 54% free 2738K/5895K, external 884K/1038K, paused 6ms+3ms
    01-12 15:12:45.579: D/dalvikvm(416): GC_CONCURRENT freed 426K, 55% free 2696K/5895K, external 884K/1038K, paused 6ms+3ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the second problem is that you're misunderstanding jsonp. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) puts it nicely:

> Requests for JSONP retrieve not JSON, but arbitrary JavaScript code.
>   They are evaluated by the JavaScript interpreter, not parsed by a JSON
>   parser.

If you want to use the `success` and `error` methods, you should rather use straight `json` as the dataType. Here's a very basic example (note, won't work with IE because it has `console.log` in the code - if you're using IE, just remove those lines):

```
  <html>
    <head>
      <script src="js/jquery.js" ></script>
      <script language="javascript">
      $(function() {
        var output = $('#output');

        $.ajax( {
              url: "test.json",
              timeout: 5000,
              dataType: "json",
              success: function(data, status){
                  $.each(data, function(i,item){ 
                      var landmark = '<h1>'+item.name+'</h1>'
                      + '<p>'+item.latitude+'<br>'
                      + item.longitude+'</p>';

                      output.append(landmark);
                  });
              },
              error: function(err, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                 output.text("There was an error [" + textStatus + "] loading the data.");
                 console.log(err);
                 console.log(errorThrown);
              }      
        });
      });
      </script>
    </head>
  <body>
  <div id="output"></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

and test.json on my server looks like this:

```
  [
     { "name": "First", "latitude": 100, "longitude": 120 },
     { "name": "Second", "latitude": -23, "longitude": -20 },
     { "name": "Third", "latitude": 40, "longitude": 120 }
  ]
```

Hope that helps, Craig

Comment: where should i locate the test.json

Comment: The test.json in this example is in the same directory as my test.html file. Hence the url is just "test.json".

Comment: But i saw this website http://samcroft.co.uk/2011/updated-loading-data-in-phonegap-using-jquery-1-5/.they are using jsonp and display the output.i tried this i didnt get it what is that problem

Comment: Hmm... it seems to me that the samcroft article is wrong. If you look at his php, you'll see that it ends with: `echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($records) . ');';`, which would therefore call the named jsoncallback method. I'll try to put together a better explanation of what is happening here, and put it in a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is listed in the error list you provide:

```
    01-12 15:10:12.359: E/Web Console(416): ReferenceError: Can't find variable:
        onDeviceReady at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:13
```

PhoneGap recommends a slightly different model to the standard DOM <body onload /> approach. You've bound to the device ready event with:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
```

Now you need to implement the 'onDeviceReady' function, for example, between the <script> tags:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    alert("I'm ready!");
}
```

That will eliminate your first problem ;-) You might have another:

```
    01-12 15:08:52.230: W/System.err(338): java.net.SocketException:
        Permission denied
```

This will be because the page you're loading is trying to reach a URL on a different server (http:192.168.1.3:8000/index): is this the same address from which you're serving your html page?

Comment: no.. this is my webaddress http://samcroft.co.uk/demos/updated-load-data-into-phonegap/landmarks.php

Comment: i am getting this example from this website..http://samcroft.co.uk/2011/updated-loading-data-in-phonegap-using-jquery-1-5/

Comment: instead of that (http:192.168.1.3:8000/index):i put another website address link http://www.samcroft.co.uk/demos/updated-load-data-into-phonegap/landmark.php.when i run the program the android emulator shows blank and white screen

Comment: first problem had been solved.but next one is socketexception permission denied

Comment: i checked my manifest file.i put all the permissison like internet.but still i have the same problem in socket exception

Answer (score 0):

The difference between dataType `json` and `jsonp` is that `json` will return json data that will be parsed by `JSON.parse` while `jsonp` will simply retrieve and execute a javascript script from the given URL (although it will also execute the success method, if you have one.)

When using jsonp, therefore, the data I fetch from the server will look like this (I'm calling it `testp.js`):

```
jsonpCallback(
     [
        { "name": "First", "latitude": 100, "longitude": 120 },
        { "name": "Second", "latitude": -23, "longitude": -20 },
        { "name": "Third", "latitude": 40, "longitude": 120 }
     ]
);
```

My `testp.html` is then:

```
  <html>
    <head>
      <script src="js/jquery.js" ></script>
      <script language="javascript">
      $(function() {
        var output = $('#output');

        $.ajax( {
              url: "testp.js",
              timeout: 5000,
              dataType: "jsonp",
              jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',
              success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                 alert('In success method');
              },
              error: function(err, textStatus, errorThrown){
                 output.text("There was an error [" + textStatus + "] loading the data.");
                 console.log(err);
                 console.log(errorThrown);
              }      
        });
      });

      function jsonpCallback(data) {
        var output = $('#output');
         $.each(data, function(i,item){ 
             var landmark = '<h1>'+item.name+'</h1>'
             + '<p>'+item.latitude+'<br>'
             + item.longitude+'</p>';

             output.append(landmark);
         });
     }
      </script>
    </head>
  <body>
  <div id="output"></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

There are two important points:

1. When using jsonp, I provide the name of the function I want to have called with the retrieved data. jQuery puts this into the `callback` parameter as part of the request, so the request the browser makes is `http://localhost/test/testp.js?callback=jsonpCallback&_=1326369112478`. My testp.js should not, obviously, be hard-coding this callback, but rather be using the provided parameter to call the appropriate callback method.
2. While my `jsonpCallback` function gets called, so does the `success` method. Logically, though, the proper place for your processing code is in the `jsonpCallback` method, per my example.

The advantage of `jsonp` over `json` is that jsonp can request a script from a different server from the one hosting the page making the request. This permits cross-site scripting.